# Bayesian error-in-variables (total least squares) model in R using MCMCglmm

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian, mixed-models, mcmc

I am fitting some Bayesian linear mixed models using the `MCMCglmm` package in `R`. My data includes predictors that are measured with error. I'd therefore like to build a model that takes this into account. My understanding is that a basic mixed effects model in `MCMCglmm` will minimize error only for the response variable (as in `ols` regression). In other words, vertical errors will be minimized. I'd like to minimize errors orthogonal to the regression line/plane/hyperplane.

1. Is it possible to fit an error-in-variables (aka total least
   squares) model using `MCMCglmm` or would I have to use JAGS/STAN to
   do this?
2. Is it possible to do this with multiple predictors in the
       same model (I have some models with 3 or 4 predictors, each measured
       with error)?
3. If it is possible, how would I specify the model?

I've included a data set below, with a random variable `height` that is measured with error to illustrate a basic set up with `MCMCglmm`.

```
library(nlme)
library(MCMCglmm)

data(Orthodont)

set.seed(1234)

Orthodont$height <- c(rnorm(54, 170, 10), rnorm(54, 150, 10))

prior1 <- list(
    B = list(mu = rep(0, 3), V = diag(1e+08, 3)), 
    G = list(G1 = list(V = 1, nu = 1, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 1000)), 
    R = list(V = 1, nu = 0.002)
)

model1 <- MCMCglmm(
    fixed = distance ~ height + Sex,   
    random = ~ Subject, 
    rcov = ~ units,
    data = Orthodont, 
    family = "gaussian",  
    prior = prior1,
    nitt = 1.1e+4, 
    thin = 10, 
    burnin = 1e+3,
    verbose = FALSE
)

summary(model1)
```